# Controlling the FormsAuthentication createPersistentCookie expiration

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc-2

In an ASP.NET MVC2 app, we have the standard login action...

```
if (ValidateUser(model.Email, model.Password)
{
  FormsAuthentication.SetAuthCookie(model.Email, model.RememberMe);
  ...
```

where the second parameter to SetAuthCookie is `createPersistentCookie` with the following documentation:

```
createPersistentCookie
  Type: System.Boolean
    true to create a persistent cookie
    (one that is saved across browser sessions); otherwise, false.
```

We would like to have the persistent cookie expire after 2 weeks (i.e., a user could return to the site within 2 weeks and not be required to re-authenticate.  After that time they would be asked to login again).

How do we set the expiration for the persistent cookie?

Answer (score 38, accepted):

Can you not do this?

```
<system.web>
    <authentication mode="Forms">
          <forms timeout="20160"/>
    </authentication>
</system.web>
```

The timeout is in minutes.

This timeout value is irrespective of whether or not you are creating a persistent cookie. It simply says that if you don't explicitly terminate the cookie (FormsAuthentication.SignOut), it will automatically expire after the given time period.

In other words, if you do:

```
FormsAuthentication.SetAuthCookie(someMembershipName, false);
```

Will result in the cookie expiring when:

- The user closes the browser, or
- The timeout is reached.

As opposed to if you do:

```
FormsAuthentication.SetAuthCookie(someMembershipName, true);
```

Will result in the cookie only expiring when the timeout is reached.

HTH

**EDIT**:

Take from [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/1d3t3c61.aspx):

the **timeout** attribute is described as follows:

> Specifies the time, in integer
>   minutes, after which the cookie
>   expires. If the SlidingExpiration
>   attribute is true, the timeout
>   attribute is a sliding value, expiring
>   at the specified number of minutes
>   after the time that the last request
>   was received. To prevent compromised
>   performance, and to avoid multiple
>   browser warnings for users who have
>   cookie warnings turned on, the cookie
>   is updated when more than half of the
>   specified time has elapsed. This might
>   cause a loss of precision. The default
>   is "30" (30 minutes).
>
> Note Under ASP.NET V1.1 persistent
>   cookies do not time out, regardless of
>   the setting of the timeout attribute.
>   **However, as of ASP.NET V2.0,
>   persistent cookies do time out
>   according to the timeout attribute**.

In other words, this expiration setting handles the Forms Authentication cookie only.

The Forms Authentication cookie is a client-side cookie, it has nothing to do with other server-side session you may have (ie a Shopping Cart).

That Session is expired with the following setting:

```
<sessionstate 
      mode="inproc"
      cookieless="false" 
      timeout="20"
```

Comment: My understanding is that this timeout controls session expiration.  Our session timeouts are on the order of 2 hours.  It's not that we want the session to last for two weeks, but rather the "remember me" cookie to last for that time.

Comment: Thanks for the follow-through.  I'll do some testing with Firebug and session expiration and report back.  In the meantime, +1 and I've accepted your answer.  Thanks again.

Comment: @Rob: no worries, let me know if you find any probs (as we use the above setting and seems to work fine in all scenarios)

Comment: hi, what is the exact time of <forms timeout="20160"/> ? 20160 makes how long it is taking?